# How to exclude every number that has 1 and print the rest that the user has inputted and match the inputted number with printed numbers?

Tags: java, loops, skip

I'm having trouble coding this program in JAVA

Ask the user an integer number then print 1 to n where is input number. if the number have a 1 skip that number and make sure match the length of n number to the output.

Example:

input: 22

output 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 20 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 32 33 34 35 - Total of 22 numbers

skipped all numbers with 1 and matched the length of the inputted numbers

I tried doing conditional statements, nested ifs and for loop but i failed and i badly need some lessons so i can understand the logic

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: java my bad i havent included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; count < num; i++) {
            if (String.valueOf(i).contains("1")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            count++;
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you do not want to use String.valueOf() you can go like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; count < num; i++) {
            int val = i;
            boolean hasOne = false;
            while (val > 0) {
                if (val % 10 == 1) {
                    hasOne = true;
                    break;
                }
                val = val / 10;
            }
            if (hasOne) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            count++;
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! though i might ask if theres another solution to this problem with the help of "%" and "/" while using conditional statements and without using the

if (String.valueOf(i).contains("1"))

Comment: @DarkDimensionZ see the update. By the way, I think you should do your homework yourself and not ask here (just in case). If you have a problem with your code, we would be happy to help you. just it is not good to ask for the whole code.

Comment: i appreciate this sir Abbas, i only have a problem with the logic, i tried this to the point of my brain, i am an apprentice 1st year college i am also learning with this code of yours too, again i am very thankful and thank you